# why are convex functions defined as functions who's epigraph is a convex set?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, definition

A convex real-function is a function such that all points **above** the function's graph form a convex set.

Why isn't it defined instead the opposite way: a function such that all points **below** it form a convex set?

**Is there a particular reason for this?**

**edit**: my question really is: Is there some kind of similarity that convex sets share with convex functions, but not with concave functions, which would explain why we use the same term for these different things?

Comment: Well, we'd have to rewrite all of the other definitions of convexity if we did that, too. For instance, twice differentiable functions would need _negative_ semidefinite Hessians, and the secant test would need the direction of its inequality reversed.

Comment: We would also lose some nice conceptual analogies. For example, if I consider a physical model of a 2D convex function, and I were to drop a ball somewhere on its surface, then it will tend to move towards the minimum due to gravitational pull, no matter where it is placed. Not so with what we call a "concave" function, and what you are proposing hypothetically to call "convex".

Comment: And our examples of "canonical" convex functions would change to more verbose and inelegant alternatives: $f(x)=-x^2$, $f(x)=-|x|$, and so forth. All we'd have is the lowly logarithm. Eventually people would throw up their hands and say "can we just ditch all of the negative signs here and switch our definition around?"

Comment: I don't see the conceptual analogy with the ball example. Why not simply call a function where such a ball would go to the minimum, a "concave" function? If we would switch concave and convex everywhere, how would that make the conceptual analogy dissapear?

i.e. why not instead of writing negative signs, simply speak of those canonical functions as  concave functions? 

Am I missing something in your point?

Comment: Why not call convex sets concave sets?

Comment: Convex functions have more elegant and natural definitions even divorced from their direct relationship to convex sets. Thus the connection between the two is more powerful. Thus they should share the same term.

Comment: I don't know why convex sets are called such, but given that they are called such, I am looking for why convex functions have the same name. Are you basically saying the reason they have the same name is merely because they both have natural definitions, as compared to the concave counterpart? That doesn't seem like a good reason to give them the same name.

Comment: It's a fantastic reason. I guess we agree to disagree.

Comment: Note that I've +1 up your question, so please do not misinterpret the volume of my disagreement with an opinion this question should not be here :-) it's very interesting, and I would be curious to see if someone could find the earliest historical references to the term convex has applied to functions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is odd. The words "convex" and "concave" have a meaning in ordinary English, and it's bad if their meaning in mathematics is something entirely different. In ordinary English, concave means hollowed out (like a cave, if you like), cupped, scooped out; convex means humped, rounded, hill-like, protruding.

The graph of a (mathematically) convex function is (English) convex if you view it from below, and (English) concave if you view it from above. One could argue that viewing from above is more natural. If you believe that, then the mathematical definition of convex is inconsistent with everyday English.

The same problem exists with convex sets. A (math) convex set is (English) convex when viewed from the outside, and (English) concave when viewed from the inside. Arguably, viewing things from the outside is the more common situation, so the choice in this case is easier to defend.

Comment: Perhaps you can offer more insight into what these words mean in ordinary English. I'm not seeing how you've applied the English definition to functions. To sets it seems more straightforward.

Comment: That said I don't agree that a convex set looks concave when viewed from the inside. It looks like... I'm inside a convex set ;-)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking of quasiconvex, and I even botched that. I'll remove that last paragraph.